# PHPUnit cannot locate Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase when outside of base "tests" folder

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

I'm running Wamp Server with PHP 5.3.4, Zend 1.11.11, and PHPUnit 3.7.1.  The structure of my project is the default Zend layout with the tests folder organized as such:

```
tests/
   application/
   library/
   bootstrap.php
   phpunit.xml
   IndexControllerTest.php
```

Where both `application/` and  `library/` are empty.  This base case works fine with my current setup, where I can run `phpunit IndexControllerTest` from terminal and it runs the tests without fault. The problem arises as soon as I move IndexControllerTest.php to a different location (say, within the `application/` directory).  I then receive a fatal error from phpunit:

```
PHP Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase' not found in 
X:\Program Files (x86)\Wamp\www\Local_site\Zend\login\tests\application\IndexControllerTest.php 
on line 3
```

Now unless I'm mistaken, the Autoloader should be taking care of this `require()`, but something is going wrong as soon as I change the location of my test file.  I have tried tweaking the phpunit.xml file over and over, but I am not sure if that is where my problem lies, or in my bootstrap.php, or in my code.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.  Even a nudge in the right direction.  Here are the relevant files:

**phpunit.xml**

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./bootstrap.php">
<testsuites>
<testsuite name="My Project">
    <directory>./tests</directory>
</testsuite>

</testsuites>

<filter>
    <!-- If Zend Framework is inside your project's library, uncomment this filter -->

    <whitelist>
        <directory suffix=".php">/library/Zend</directory>
    </whitelist>

</filter>
</phpunit>
```

**bootstrap.php**

```
<?php

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'testing'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));


require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

**IndexControllerTest.php**

```
<?php
class IndexControllerTest extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{
    protected $application;

    public function setUp() 
    {
        // Assign and instantiate in one step:
        $this->bootstrap = new Zend_Application(
            'testing',
            APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
            );
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testTrue()
    {
         $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

As per other suggestions from the golden internet, I also altered my php/php.ini include_path to be:

```
include_path=".;X:\Program Files (x86)\Wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4\pear;X:\Program Files (x86)\Wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4\pear\PHPUnit"
```

Do I need to explicitly include `Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php`?  I've tried hundreds of solutions already, but I've been flying blind so I could have been very close and not even known it.

Comment: from where do you run phpunit when you moved the *Test.php file? Does the config file get loaded in that case?

Comment: As in, am I running `phpunit application/IndexControllerTest` if IndexControllerTest.php is located in tests/application/IndexControllerTest.php?  Yes I did (and same error), and it doesn't produce any errors for the config file not being loaded.  Even if I move the config file (which I am assuming is phpunit.xml), to within tests/application I still receive the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a solution (as simple as it is...) to this problem.  For whatever reason phpunit.xml was not bootstrapping my bootstrap.php file.  All it required was requiring my bootstrap before I declared my class in IndexControllerTest.php:

**IndexControllerTest**

```
require_once '/path/to/bootstrap.php';

IndexControllerTest extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{
      public function testTrue() 
      {
              $this->assertTrue(true);
      }
}
```

It seems odd having to require this in each test file, and I am sure I will find a more permanent solution soon.  Hopefully this helps someone.

**EDIT**

Slightly better solution found where I simply copied my phpunit.xml file to the same directory as IndexControllerTest and changed `bootstrap="bootstrap.php"` to `bootstrap="../bootstrap.php"` in the new phpunit.xml file.  Now no `require_once` is needed for all test files in that directory.  Still seems like a rough fix, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this for the past few hours and using the answer I managed to come up with the following which I added to my application/bootstrap.php

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader/Resource.php';

$resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
'basePath'      => APPLICATION_PATH,
'namespace'     => '',
'resourceTypes' => array(
    'cplib' => array(
        'path'      => 'library/CP',
        'namespace' => 'CP_'
    ),
),
));
```

Once I has this in place I was able to autoload the correct Zend library files with out having to manually specify them.

Answer (score 0):

you should not need to include the bootstrap file explicitly in your test cases.

you need to have the library folder (which contains the Zend library) on the include path. the bootstrap.php file should be responsible for that.

this error message have two possible reasons:

1. the phpunit.xml could not refer to the correct bootstrap.php.
2. the bootstrap file does not reference the correct library path (I think this is the case here)

You can echo the include path inside the bootstrap.php to make sure it is set correctly.

Basically, add the following lines to bootstrap.php before the require_once

```
$includePath  = get_include_path();
echo "appPath = ".APPLICATION_PATH. "\n";
echo "includePath = $includePath \n";
```

The includePath should have an entry for the application/library folder 
(note that there are 2 application folders. one holding the classes and the other holding the tests. you should be referring to the one outside the tests directory)

[here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/project-structure.project.html) is the typical folder structure.